# Signal Flow Diagram for a biquadratic section

Tags: amplifier, filter, transfer-function, diagram

I'm doing a theoretical preparation for an Electronics laboratory. This laboratory is about Tow-Thomas biquadratic section which can be represented by the following circuit:

[image]

The first thing that is asked on the guide is to do a signal flow diagram of this circuit without analising it(just using logic). My teacher didn't teach me how to do it. He just show me the solution in one of his apresentation slides:

[image]

I know that the first sub-circuit is a **summing-inverter amplifier** (if we consider the equivalent impedance of \$Z_{C_1}\$ and \$R_6\$), the second a **integrator-inverter amplifier** and the third a **multiplicator-inverter amplifier**. So, I know how he obtained at least the coefficients in the two last boxes (but only if \$R_5=R_2\$ which is given by the guide). My problem is about  the term on the first box and where do \$\frac{1}{Q}\$ and \$K\$ came from?

I think we can't immediately associate \$\frac{1}{Q}\$ to an element of the circuit, or just saying that is there a \$K\$ which corresponds to the \$DC\$ gain for second an third sub-circuts ( I just figure it out the significance of \$K\$ after some extense circuit analysis ).

So, I think this is about usual logic. If this is a circuit of a usual and well known group circuits (which I didn't know in the first place), then there's some way to do the signal flow diagram immediately. One thing that I noticed is that if we change, for example the value of one resistance then the diagram could be a little bit different. So, to do immediately this  diagram we need to assume that the values for those resistances and capacitances aren't random.

Can you advise me some interesting links about signal flow diagrams, or explain how would you do to get immedately the diagram of this circuit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relation between the circuit diagram and the signal flow diagram will become clearer when you have the corresponding 2nd-order transfer function H(s).Note that you can define three different functions (you have three output terminals) - but all with the same denominator (V2 and V3 are the lowpass outputs, V1 gives a bandpass function).

In this case, you will see that the resitor R6 controls the Q-value of the second-order filter function. This Q-value determines the lowpass characteristic (Butterworth, Chebyshev,...) and the bandpass selectivity, respectively. The corresponding formula for Q can be derived from the transfer function.

More than that, the first block is an inverting first-order lowpass (identical to an integrator stage with damping) which can add two different signals (feedback and input). Hence, you can split this block into two separate units: A summing block and a damped integrator (integrator with additional resistive feedback).

The factor K is simply the DC gain of the lowpass filter identical to R4/P2.

**EDIT:**
I suggest to find the transfer functions for both - the circuit diagram as well as for the signal flow diagram. Then you can compare the various parts of the denominator and find the relations between both diagrams. However, it is important, that both functions are written in the so-called "normal form", which means: Nominator N(s)=(1+s*A+s²*B).

Comment: Could you explain why on the superior branch is there a +1 instead something else?

Comment: And how did you get K?

Comment: I know these are too many questions but I can tell that you have some kind of ability to analyse circuits with only your eyes (which I don't have). What is your procedure to conclude what I asked?

Comment: Are you able to find (calculate) the transfer functions for both arrangements? If not, we can give you some help. It is nothing else than to find the solution for a set of three equqation with three unknowns.

Comment: I have already done it... So, you mean that isn't possible to draw the diagram with all those prominores before computing something?

Comment: I do not understand this question. When you have both transfer functions - you can compare the various terms for s and s². What else do you need?

Comment: Yes, but I want to draw the diagram before having any transfer function.

Comment: Forget it, I just need to have some practice on this type of circuits

Comment: Yes - for example you must know that the first block can be split into one summer (summing up three inputs) and an integrator with a damping feedback path. All other parts are simple, for my opinion.